# Logstash using ruby filter, How are ElasticSearch id controll?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-filter

I use Java ElasticSearch api.
One search, average search result 17,000,000 data
Therefore i ElasticSearch api used a scrolling method.

One ElasticSearch data update is required.
and update use needs '_id'.
However, the search result source does not include '_id'.

And I thought of a way !

"I want to use the Logstash Filter to include '_id' in the ElasticSearch Source."

but, i don't know way ElasticSearch source include '_id' :( ...

Help me !

if other way, Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `_id` of a hit in Java API using `SearchHit.getId()`: https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.0.0/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchHit.html#getId--.

Comment: i new asked... please check : ) "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028794/elasticsearch-use-java-api-scrolledpage-class-i-want-getid"