# ElasticSearch use java API "ScrolledPage.class", i want getId

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i asked ElasticSearch java api.
i listen solution. however it is do not solution.

so, i ask again.

i use java source. 
please your checking my sourcecode.

```
ScrolledPage<Map> scroll = (ScrolledPage<Map>) 
elasticsearchOperations.startScroll(999999999, query, Map.class);
List<Map> documents = new LinkedList<>();
while (scroll.hasContent()) {
    for (Map docs : scroll.getContent()) {z
        documents.add(docs);
    }
    scroll = (ScrolledPage<Map>) elasticsearchOperations.continueScroll(scroll.getScrollId(),999999999,Map.class);
    System.out.println();
}
return documents;
```

now i useing in java source, but "ScrolledPage.class" doesn't have "SearchHit.getId()" method.

Is there no other way?

### dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- rest full -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>sniffer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- transpoort -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- es main-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- make json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mariaDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Which jar / maven dependency (including version) do you use for connecting to elasticsearch?

Comment: ElasticSearch using version 5.5.0.
 and modify contends complete.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at `documents.add(docs)` and write what are the types of the key and value in the map?

Comment: My problem is solved. StartScroll was used because of the number of searches found in ElasticSearch. But I found that I could set the number of searches found in ElasticSearch. I applied this and used the queryForPage method. Thank you for your help.